# MongoDB Aggregate Group and Summarise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an aggregate function that works well by grouping data from 2 collections by Month.

```
    var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "merchant": new ObjectID("5f2a4e4efb740d9c6e810d67")
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m",
                    "date": "$purchaseDate"
                }
            },
            "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice": {
                "$sum": "$warrantyWholesalePrice"
            },
            "totalWarrantyPrice": {
                "$sum": "$warrantyPrice"
            },
            "totalSaleAmount": {
                "$sum": "$purchasePrice"
            },
            "totalCoverAmount": {
                "$sum": "$suggestedRetailPrice"
            },
            "totalContracts": {
                "$sum": 1.0
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "transactions",
            "let": {
                "statementMonth": "$_id"
            },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$addFields": {
                        "transMonth": {
                            "$dateToString": {
                                "format": "%Y-%m",
                                "date": "$date"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$eq": [
                                "$$statementMonth",
                                "$transMonth"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "transactions"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$transactions",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "totalContracts": {
                "$first": "$totalContracts"
            },
            "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice": {
                "$first": "$totalWarrantyWholesalePrice"
            },
            "totalWarrantyPrice": {
                "$first": "$totalWarrantyPrice"
            },
            "totalSaleAmount": {
                "$first": "$totalSaleAmount"
            },
            "totalCoverAmount": {
                "$first": "$totalCoverAmount"
            },
            "totalAmountPaid": {
                "$sum": "$transactions.amountPaid"
            },
            "totalAmountDue": {
                "$sum": "$totalAmountDue"
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "totalAmountDue": {
                "$subtract": [
                    "$totalWarrantyPrice",
                    "$totalWarrantyWholesalePrice"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1.0,
            "totalContracts": 1.0,
            "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice": 1.0,
            "totalWarrantyPrice": 1.0,
            "totalSaleAmount": 1.0,
            "totalCoverAmount": 1.0,
            "totalAmountPaid": 1.0,
            "totalAmountDue": {
                "$round": [
                    "$totalAmountDue",
                    2.0
                ]
            },
            "balance": {
                "$round": [
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            "$totalAmountDue",
                            "$totalAmountPaid"
                        ]
                    },
                    2.0
                ]
            },
            "status": {
                "$switch": {
                    "branches": [
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    {
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            "$totalAmountDue",
                                            "$totalAmountPaid"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    0.0
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "PAID"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$and": [
                                    {
                                        "$gt": [
                                            {
                                                "$subtract": [
                                                    "$totalAmountDue",
                                                    "$totalAmountPaid"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            0.0
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$gt": [
                                            "$totalAmountPaid",
                                            0.0
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "PARTIAL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "default": "DUE"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": -1.0
        }
    }
];
```

This produces the following output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "2020-08", 
    "totalContracts" : 10.0, 
    "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(109), 
    "totalWarrantyPrice" : 163.55, 
    "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(9000), 
    "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(10000), 
    "totalAmountPaid" : 47.0, 
    "totalAmountDue" : 54.55, 
    "balance" : 7.55, 
    "status" : "PARTIAL"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2020-07", 
    "totalContracts" : 1.0, 
    "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(23), 
    "totalWarrantyPrice" : NumberInt(40), 
    "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(900), 
    "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(1000), 
    "totalAmountPaid" : NumberInt(0), 
    "totalAmountDue" : NumberInt(17), 
    "balance" : NumberInt(17), 
    "status" : "DUE"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2020-06", 
    "totalContracts" : 1.0, 
    "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(0), 
    "totalWarrantyPrice" : NumberInt(0), 
    "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(900), 
    "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(1000), 
    "totalAmountPaid" : NumberInt(0), 
    "totalAmountDue" : NumberInt(0), 
    "balance" : NumberInt(0), 
    "status" : "PAID"
}
```

However, I would like to summarise the monthly groups, while also displaying the monthly summaries. I can work out how to complete either with two aggregators, however I would like to consolidate this into one. How can I achieve the following?

```
{ 
    lifetimeTotals: {
        "totalContracts" : 12.0,
        "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(132), 
        "totalWarrantyPrice" : 203.55, 
        "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(9900), 
        "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(11000), 
        "totalAmountPaid" : 47.0, 
        "totalAmountDue" : 71.55, 
        "balance" : 24.55, 
    },
    monthTotals: {
        "2020-08": {
            "totalContracts" : 10.0, 
            "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(109), 
            "totalWarrantyPrice" : 163.55, 
            "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(9000), 
            "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(10000), 
            "totalAmountPaid" : 47.0, 
            "totalAmountDue" : 54.55, 
            "balance" : 7.55, 
            "status" : "PARTIAL"
        },
        "2020-07": {
            "totalContracts" : 1.0, 
            "totalWarrantyWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(23), 
            "totalWarrantyPrice" : NumberInt(40), 
            "totalSaleAmount" : NumberInt(900), 
            "totalCoverAmount" : NumberInt(1000), 
            "totalAmountPaid" : NumberInt(0), 
            "totalAmountDue" : NumberInt(17), 
            "balance" : NumberInt(17), 
            "status" : "DUE"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Take a look at [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#facet-aggregation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this with `$facet`. I wrote the a mongo query based on your last output.

1. `$facet` helps you to categorize the incoming fields. So by using `$group`, we get all sum inside `lifetimeTotals[]` as one field
2. `$map` helps to run whole / modify the current objects.
3. `$arrayToObject` is alwasy looking for key value pair. `(k:v)`. We already got it with `$map`. *key (k) as "_id" and value (v) as "{REST OF OTHER FIELDS}".*

Here is the code

```
[
  {
    $facet: {
      lifetimeTotals: [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            totalContracts: {
              $sum: "$totalContracts"
            },
            totalWarrantyWholesalePrice: {
              $sum: "$totalWarrantyWholesalePrice"
            },
            totalWarrantyPrice: {
              $sum: "$totalWarrantyPrice"
            },
            /** Rest of other fields*/
            
          }
        }
      ],
      months: [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lifetimeTotals: 1,
      monthTotals: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$months",
            in: {
              k: "$$this._id",
              v: {
                totalContracts: "$$this.totalContracts",
                totalWarrantyWholesalePrice: "$$this.totalWarrantyWholesalePrice",
                totalWarrantyPrice: "$$this.totalWarrantyPrice"
                /** Rest of other fields*/
                
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TbXOfrxhb8g)